# How to set a color in xslt once for all fields

Tags: variables, xslt, colors

Can I set a variable or something to lets say "red" once and when i want some font to be red i just call that variable? that way i can edit the color of all specified text with ease for future possibilities. I'm new to xslt and appreciate any help. thank you.

Edit: adding some code with what i would want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<!--Probably declare the variable here-->
<!--Like <variable=outputcolor value="red" -->
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-portrait"
                page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="2cm">
                <fo:region-body />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-family="Helvetica"
                font-size="6pt">
                <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-indent="5pt">
                    <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:text>Application Summary</xsl:text></fo:inline>
                        <!--Here i would like to make red a variable that i could possibly changed -->
                        <!--like fo:inline color="{outputcolor}"-->
                    <fo:inline color="red">
                        <xsl:value-of select="businessInfo/appSum" />
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Post some example code (XML + XSLT + expected output) if you want a more specific answer. In addition, if your output is HTML, you can use CSS to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `attribute-set` is an option worth exploring. Another option is to do what you started to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!--Probably declare the variable here-->
    <xsl:variable name="outputcolor" select="'red'" />
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-portrait"
                page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="2cm">
                <fo:region-body />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-family="Helvetica"
                font-size="6pt">
                <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-indent="5pt">
                    <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:text>Application Summary</xsl:text></fo:inline>
                    <!--Here i would like to make red a variable that i could possibly changed -->
                    <fo:inline color="{$outputcolor}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="businessInfo/appSum" />
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that declaring the variable at the top level of the template limits its scope to that template only. You can declare global variables (at the top level of the stylesheet, outside of any template) to make them available anywhere in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [named attribute set](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets) as a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet`, containing the attributes you want to reuse:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="colouredText">
  <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
  <!-- you can set other attributes too: font-weight, font-style, ... -->
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

and then use it when creating elements with `xsl:copy`, `xsl:element` or with a literal result element:

```
<xsl:copy use-attribute-sets="colouredText">
    ...
</xsl:copy>

<xsl:element name="fo:inline" use-attribute-sets="colouredText">
    ...
</xsl:element>

<fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="colouredText">
    ...
</fo:inline>
```

If the output requirements change (*"Besides being red, important info must be bold also"* / *"Forget the color, just made them italic"* / *"Try using Comic Sans"*) you only need to adjust the attribute definitions inside the attribute-set, without having to modify the templates where these "styles" are applied.

The value of the `xsl:use-attribute-sets` attribute is a whitespace-separated **list** of attribute set names:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="spacedText">
  <xsl:attribute name="space-before">12pt</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="space-after">12pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

...

<fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="colouredText spacedText">
    This block is both coloured and spaced!
</fo:block>
```

An attribute set can in turn refer to other sets:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="colouredTitle" use-attribute-sets="colouredText">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">16pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

The linked section of the XSL 1.0 specifications (or [the corresponding section of the XSL 2.0 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-sets)) provides further information about how attribute sets can be extended and merged.